# Space of homogeneous type for R^n with different measures

Tags: real-analysis, integration, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

The problem is:

> Show that $(\mathbb{R}^d,d_2,(1+\|x\|^\alpha)dx)$ is a space of homogeneous type for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, where $d_2$ is the Euclidean metric.

The definition of **space of homogeneous type** is:

> Definition: We say that $(E,d,\mu)$ is a space of homogeneous type if the followings hold:
>
> 1. $(E,d)$ is a quasi-metric space;
> 2. there exists some $C \in [1,+\infty[$ such that for any $x \in E$ and any $r>0$, $\mu(B(x,2r)) \leq C\mu(B(x,r)) < +\infty$.

In this case, the goal is to show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and any $r>0$,
\[ \int_{B(x,2r)} (1+\|y\|)^\alpha dy \leq C \int_{B(x,r)} (1+\|y\|)^\alpha dy \]
Obviously, the main work is to approximate the integration on a ball not centered at the origin and get the constant free of $x$ and $r$ (either one is easy, while controlling both of them requires rather hard effort).

Could anyone give a proper approximation? Your help is greatly appreciated in advance!